# Stateless functional component method never gets fresh data from Redux store, but others do

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, ag-grid

I got into some trouble.
I have a pretty common functional component connected to Redux via mapStateToProps:

```
    const TableWrapper = ({ studentsSelection }) => {

  const onComponentStateChanged = params =>
    params.api.forEachNode(node =>
      studentsSelection.selectedStudents.findIndex(student =>
        student.number === node.data.number) >= 0 &&
      node.setSelected(true)
    );

  const gridOptions = getGridOptions(onComponentStateChanged(), onSelection);

  return (
    <BootStrapTableWrapper>
      <Table gridOptions={gridOptions} />
    </BootStrapTableWrapper>
  );
};
TableWrapper.propTypes = {
  studentsSelection: PropTypes.shape({
    selectedStudents: PropTypes.array
  })
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  studentsSelection: state.gpCreationWizard.studentsSelection
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(TableWrapper);
```

Where getGridOption refers to this:

```
const getStudentsSelectionGridOptions = (onComponentStateChanged, updateStudentsSelectionSelectionAction) => ({
    ...studentsSelectionGridOptions,
    onComponentStateChanged(props) {
        onComponentStateChanged(props);
    },
    onRowSelected({node}) {
        updateStudentsSelectionSelectionAction(node);
    },
});

export default getStudentsSelectionGridOptions;
```

And resulted gridOptions are used for Ag-Grid table.

So let me explain the business function: I'm using Ag-Grid table, and when user select some students, they are added to the Redux store. Then I'm using the `onComponentStateChanged` to keep the selection on pagination. So if user changed the page, and the old data will be replaced by new one, I want the selection to be kept when he's gonna return back. But **the problem** is that `onComponentStateChanged` is always referring to the same `studentsSelection.selectedStudents` (but other methods and render receiving new data). So this is probably something about js scopes. Please, what should I do to make this function be using the new data, not the old one. I tried to wrap that one in anther function, but that didn't have any effect. The funny fact, that this works fine for class component and this.props referring. If I explained that not very clear, please ask about more details.

Comment: can you show getGridOptions please?

Comment: @ChrisCousins hello! getGridOptions = getStudentsSelectionGridOptions, it's renamed in import. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

not sure what getGridOptions does... but I think the problem is, you are calling the method instead of passing the method, so change:

`const gridOptions = getGridOptions(onComponentStateChanged(), onSelection);`

to:

`const gridOptions = getGridOptions(onComponentStateChanged, onSelection);`

so `onComponentStateChanged` is sent as method and not the result of calling it

Comment: if not, `params` is never used

Comment: Probably that's not the case, because onComponentStateChanged returns a function, which are used in getStudentsSelectionGridOptions. I did it consciously.

Comment: onComponentStateChanged doesn't resturn  a function, is a function. and you are calling it with params as undefined, so it must be crashing atm... the console doesn't show anything?

Comment: whoops. my bad, didn't notice that. I copied that with an error, actually it looks like  `const gridOptions = getGridOptions(onComponentStateChanged, onSelection);`

Comment: but still no effect. I have a feeling, that Ag-Grid for some reason somehow changing  the function's scope and that react no more for new data.

Comment: and... this part ` && node.setSelected(true)` is strange... are you sure `setSelected(...)` returns true/false or something? I would guess that setSelection sets the selection

Comment: yes, you are right. that is responsible for setting the selection, I was just lazy to write if statement :)

Comment: oh ok, I don't see anything else wrong in your code... you are saying the property never change... are you sure that the state holds the new state value in `state.gpCreationWizard.studentsSelection`? like is `gpCreationWizard` right?

Comment: absolutely. new value comes for every other method and in `return`. Only that function remains with the old one.